# How to shift to forms based on option selected in combobox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a windows form app in vb 2010 that contains a combobox and a button. The next form to be shown depends on the option selected by user. How do i put this code in the event of clicking a button?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could do something like that:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim nextForm As Form = Nothing
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedText
        Case "Option 1"
            nextForm = New Form2()
        Case "Option 2"
            nextForm = New Form3()
    End Select
    If nextForm IsNot Nothing Then
        nextForm.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MattWilko Hey now, we were all beginners once :)